# Creating help documentation for my asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, documentation-generation, chm

I have developed a web application in `asp.net` and for that I need to create help file. I want give a detail help for the user for each page with explaining the fields and buttons in that page. Also need to show the entire documents as help files as `chm` file when we press **F1** or click the Help menu in the application.  I have not done this before so I do not have any idea on this. I browsed this here and some suggested using `sandcastle` and other documentation tools. I wanted to know whether I need to create a project for help in my current application and store the help content in the database?